# Solr-based View, Row cache

Tags: views, 8, performance

Context:
Drupal 8.5, Search API Solr 2.2

There's a Solr-based view with *Field* display mode, as the results are not just nodes, there are non-Drupal content too.

Right now the dynamic page cache is not effective on the page.

Either the whole page comes from the cache or nothing. The pageload time is around 3 seconds on localhost (the rest of the site produces ~1s response times even as logged in user, due to dynamic page cache)
We did profiling, the Solr part is not significant, less than 1% of the execution, as a justification, the empty result page is like 100% faster than the page with actual results.

What's the most time consuming according to XDebug is the rendering and Twig.
One view row for the result is almost static, only the excerpt changes based on the keyword.Out of the box, for Views, is https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/auto-placeholdering active? Is it really the right way to speed up such a view?

Comment: Hey Aron, thing is, debugging always needs to be done by you. Otherwise this question simply gets too broad. As back and forth clarification about your site, your setup, "non-Drupal content", your settings, your logs etc. just go beyond the scope of this site. We basically need a reproducible problem or a specific and narrow question.

Comment: I partially agree, the very specific question here is the following: Out of the box, for Views, is https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/auto-placeholdering active?  Which isn't site specific, it's just about how Drupal and Views work together.

Comment: Well, maybe you could rewrite the question and especially its title to make it more specific, or let's say maybe you can emphasize the specific parts a bit more?